# Analyzing crashdump, wrong symbols

Tags: iis, server-crashes, dump, windbg

I am having trouble analyzing a crashdump with windbg. I run:

```
.sympath SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
.reload /f /i
```

To get the symbols. All symbols seem to have downloaded to c:\symbols and then i run:

```
analyze -v
```

To analyze. But i get "WRONG_SYMBOLS" in my result (se below). I run windbg in the same computer that the dumpfile is from (Windows Server 2008 64bit). Why don't my symbols load correctly?

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+0
000007ff`00be314a 4c8be0          mov     r12,rax

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000777530e5 (ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionTable+0x0000000000000035)
   ExceptionCode: c00000fd (Stack overflow)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 000000001d535fa8

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

USER_LCID_STR:  ENU

OS_SKU:  7

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc00000fd - A new guard page for the stack cannot be created.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000001d535fa8

RECURRING_STACK: From frames 0x34 to 0x34

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  w3wp.exe

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_STACK_OVERFLOW

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000000000000 to 0000000000000000

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  Followup set based on attribute [Is_ChosenCrashFollowupThread] from Frame:[0] on thread:[PSEUDO_THREAD]

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`1d535fb0 00000000`777531d1 : 00000000`1d536148 00000000`1d5360c8 00000000`1d536080 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionTable+0x35
00000000`1d536040 000007fe`eb806d6b : 00000000`1d536748 00000000`1d538160 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlLookupFunctionEntry+0x31
00000000`1d536070 000007fe`eb806bd9 : 00000000`1d536df0 00000000`1d538810 00000000`1d5380b8 000007fe`eb806e5d : clr!LazyMachState::unwindLazyState+0x12b
00000000`1d536700 000007fe`eb805d45 : 00000000`1d536a30 000007fe`00000000 00000000`1d5368f8 000007fe`eb986c5c : clr!HelperMethodFrame::GetFunction+0xd4
00000000`1d5367e0 000007fe`eb80609c : ffffffff`fffffffe 000007fe`eb750000 000007fe`eb750000 000007fe`e3966de8 : clr!StackFrameIterator::ProcessCurrentFrame+0x8ae
00000000`1d5368f0 000007fe`eb80638b : 00000000`1d537fa8 00000000`1d5abee0 00000000`1d5abff0 00000000`1d536a30 : clr!StackFrameIterator::NextRaw+0x35c
00000000`1d536980 000007fe`eb8064a1 : 00000000`000000dc 000007fe`eb8054e9 00000000`00000000 00000000`1d536a30 : clr!StackFrameIterator::Filter+0x1a4
00000000`1d5369c0 000007fe`eb805c96 : 00000000`1d5372a0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 000007fe`eb986c5c : clr!StackFrameIterator::Init+0xe6
00000000`1d536a00 000007fe`eb80534e : 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`000000d7 000007fe`e3966de8 : clr!Thread::StackWalkFramesEx+0x76
00000000`1d536da0 000007fe`eb8221b7 : 000007fe`ebdcefc0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`02758050 : clr!Thread::StackWalkFrames+0xb1
00000000`1d537eb0 000007fe`e38a10f6 : 00000000`02876970 00000000`12733d80 00000000`1d5382a0 000007fe`00000001 : clr!SecurityStackWalk::CheckNReturnSO+0x2b7
00000000`1d538240 000007fe`e38a109e : 00000000`03412510 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`02b31358 : mscorlib_ni+0x3810f6
00000000`1d538280 000007fe`e391d327 : 00000000`02b31358 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`01a2bb60 : mscorlib_ni+0x38109e
00000000`1d5382c0 000007fe`e391d219 : ffffffff`fffffffe 00000000`0000001c 00000000`00000000 00000000`0275dfd8 : mscorlib_ni+0x3fd327
00000000`1d538340 000007fe`e3efa480 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e38b058f 00000000`02b314e8 00000000`032dcd50 : mscorlib_ni+0x3fd219
00000000`1d538380 000007fe`e3f11e1f : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e3f11f5b 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x9da480
00000000`1d5383c0 000007fe`eb8090b4 : 00000000`00000004 00000000`0275dfd8 00000000`03411588 00000000`00000000 : mscorlib_ni+0x9f1e1f
00000000`1d538410 000007fe`eb8091c9 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!CallDescrWorker+0x84
00000000`1d538470 000007fe`eb809245 : 00000000`1d538588 00000000`00000003 00000000`1d5385a0 00000000`1d538908 : clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0xa9
00000000`1d5384f0 000007fe`eb809718 : 00000000`1d5388f0 000007fe`e3f11f30 00000000`1d538800 00000000`00000001 : clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x2a1
00000000`1d538730 000007fe`ebc6928a : 00000000`1b9313e0 00000000`1d538870 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x44
00000000`1d538770 000007fe`ebcd62e0 : 000007ff`00f256a8 000007fe`ebddd180 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`1d538e60 : clr!SecurityStackWalk::ReflectionTargetDemand+0xca
00000000`1d538930 000007fe`eb7b7972 : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`00f256a8 000007ff`00d7cd10 000007fe`00000000 : clr!AccessCheckOptions::DemandMemberAccess+0xa1
00000000`1d538a00 000007fe`eb7b7a91 : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`0062ab28 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1d539040 : clr!ClassLoader::CheckAccess+0x132
00000000`1d538ac0 000007fe`eb7c4193 : 000007ff`0062ab28 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00d7cd10 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccess+0x111
00000000`1d538bb0 000007fe`eb7b7b1a : 00000000`1d538e60 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1d538e10 00000000`00000001 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccessClass+0x226
00000000`1d538c60 000007fe`eb7b7a91 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ebfc0010 00000000`000000be : clr!ClassLoader::CheckAccess+0x3b
00000000`1d538d20 000007fe`eb7bf438 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`00000000 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00ee9278 : clr!ClassLoader::CanAccess+0x111
00000000`1d538e10 000007fe`eb7bf1bf : 000007ff`00f265b8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 000007ff`00f256a8 : clr!CEEInfo::GetFieldInfoHelper+0x238
00000000`1d538ed0 000007fe`f1c87e44 : 00000000`1d5397f0 00000000`04000005 00000000`013303b8 000007ff`00f265b9 : clr!CEEInfo::getFieldInfo+0xcf
00000000`1d538f80 000007fe`f1be8937 : 00000000`00000074 00000000`0000000d 00000000`04000005 00000000`00000074 : clrjit!ReaderBase::VerifyFieldAccess+0x110
00000000`1d539110 000007fe`f1be8cc7 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`f1c875dc 00000000`00000001 00000000`1d5398e4 : clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode_Helper+0x1157
00000000`1d539640 000007fe`f1bd22c7 : 00000000`1d5397f0 00000000`01340190 00000000`00000001 00000000`01308cb8 : clrjit!ReaderBase::readBytesForFlowGraphNode+0x197
00000000`1d5396f0 000007fe`f1bd15c6 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 000007fe`00000009 00000000`013303a8 : clrjit!ReaderBase::MSILToIR+0x1d7
00000000`1d539780 000007fe`f1bd2cae : 00000000`01a79780 00000000`1d879c20 000007fe`ebe47890 00000000`1bada2f0 : clrjit!THX_dop2+0x2c9
00000000`1d5399c0 000007fe`eb7c9853 : 00000000`1bada2f0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007fe`eb75d0ed : clrjit!PreJit::compileMethod+0xba
00000000`1d539a40 000007fe`eb7c9783 : 00000000`01aa18a0 00000000`1d539cf0 00000000`1d539e30 00000000`00800000 : clr!invokeCompileMethodHelper+0xa7
00000000`1d539ad0 000007fe`eb7c96ba : 00000000`00800000 00000000`1d539cc0 00000000`1d539cf0 000007fe`eb757f75 : clr!invokeCompileMethod+0x63
00000000`1d539b30 000007fe`eb7c94b4 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`1d539cf0 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`00800000 : clr!CallCompileMethodWithSEHWrapper+0x46
00000000`1d539bc0 000007fe`eb829944 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x270
00000000`1d53a190 000007fe`eb7b70a6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`1d53a4a8 000007ff`00f256a8 : clr!MethodDesc::IsVerifiable+0xe4
00000000`1d53a220 000007fe`eb829c1c : 00000000`00000010 00000000`1d53a3d0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xb4ef3
00000000`1d53a320 000007fe`eb7c9455 : 00000000`1b95ce60 00000000`1d53a460 00000000`1b95ce60 000007ff`0062ab28 : clr!GetCompileFlagsIfGenericInstantiation+0x83
00000000`1d53a360 000007fe`eb7f0741 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000000 : clr!UnsafeJitFunction+0x211
00000000`1d53a930 000007fe`eb7f04b8 : 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000001 000007ff`0062ab28 00000000`1baf0f00 : clr!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker+0x1dd
00000000`1d53aaa0 000007fe`ebced34c : 000007ff`00f256a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`03410dd0 00000000`00000000 : clr!MethodDesc::DoPrestub+0x522
00000000`1d53abb0 000007fe`e417d9b9 : 00000000`03411568 00000000`027f9db0 00000000`03410c88 00000000`0340d350 : clr!MethodDesc::CompileMethod+0xfc
00000000`1d53ad50 000007fe`e2dcd0ba : 00000000`03410678 00000000`03410a50 00000000`02abddc0 000007fe`eb7890f2 : mscorlib_ni+0xc5d9b9
00000000`1d53ada0 000007ff`009576f2 : 00000000`03410228 00000000`034101d8 00000000`0340daa8 00000000`0340e420 : System_Core_ni+0x2ad0ba
00000000`1d53adf0 000007ff`0095759c : 000007ff`00d043b0 00000000`02a8a240 00000000`0340e420 000007fe`e2dc3b7a : 0x000007ff`009576f2
00000000`1d53ae40 000007ff`00be315f : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`0095759c
00000000`1d53ae80 000007ff`00be314a : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be315f
00000000`1d53aef0 000007ff`00be314a : 00000000`0340d098 00000000`03410040 00000000`0340e058 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be314a
00000000`1d53af60 000007ff`00be2fa3 : 00000000`02efe748 000007ff`00c572f8 00000000`0340e058 00000000`0340de40 : 0x000007ff`00be314a
00000000`1d53afd0 000007ff`00be2e7b : 000007fe`e2e4c578 000007fe`eb7890d0 000007ff`009a7620 000007ff`009a63b0 : 0x000007ff`00be2fa3
00000000`1d53b040 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340e420 00000000`03410138 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00be2e7b
00000000`1d53b080 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`03410138 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340e480 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b0d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340e5d8 00000000`0340e480 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b130 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340e5d8 00000000`034100d8 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b180 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`034100d8 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340ef90 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b1d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340f100 00000000`0340ef90 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b230 000007ff`0095739e : 00000000`0340f100 00000000`03410078 00000000`02e85f80 00000000`03410040 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b280 000007ff`00957127 : 00000000`03410078 000007ff`009aaad0 00000000`0340f5b0 000007fe`e2dcdccf : 0x000007ff`0095739e
00000000`1d53b2d0 000007ff`00956db6 : 00000000`02e85f80 000007ff`009a9708 00000000`0340f708 00000000`0340f5b0 : 0x000007ff`00957127
00000000`1d53b330 000007ff`0095626a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0340f100 00000000`00000000 000007fe`e2dc0eb4 : 0x000007ff`00956db6
00000000`1d53b380 000007ff`0095614a : 00000000`0340e5f8 00000000`00000000 00000000`0303b008 00000000`00000000 : 0x000007ff`0095626a
00000000`1d53b3f0 000007ff`009560aa : 000007ff`009a4cd8 000007fe`e2e35c18 00000000`00000001 000007ff`00ee8908 : 0x000007ff`0095614a
00000000`1d53b450 000007fe`e2fcc15f : 00000000`0340f708 000007ff`00ee8908 00000000`0340f120 00000000`0303b008 : 0x000007ff`009560aa
00000000`1d53b480 000007ff`00d411c9 : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0340e8b8 00000000`0340e618 00000000`0340d4d8 : System_Core_ni+0x4ac15f
00000000`1d53b4e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033f3398 00000000`033f30f8 00000000`033f1fb8 : 0x000007ff`00d411c9
00000000`1d53b560 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033d7ea0 00000000`033d7c00 00000000`033d6ac0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b5e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033bc980 00000000`033bc6e0 00000000`033bb5a0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b660 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`033a1488 00000000`033a11e8 00000000`033a00a8 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b6e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03385f68 00000000`03385cc8 00000000`03384b88 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b760 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0336aa70 00000000`0336a7d0 00000000`03369690 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b7e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0334f550 00000000`0334f2b0 00000000`0334e170 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b860 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03333f40 00000000`03333ca0 00000000`03332b60 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b8e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03318a20 00000000`03318780 00000000`03317640 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b960 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`032fd528 00000000`032fd288 00000000`032fc148 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53b9e0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`032d7108 00000000`032d6e68 00000000`032d58f0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53ba60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03617568 00000000`036172c8 00000000`03616188 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bae0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035fc048 00000000`035fbda8 00000000`035fac68 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bb60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035e0b50 00000000`035e08b0 00000000`035df770 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bbe0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035c5630 00000000`035c5390 00000000`035c4250 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bc60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`035aa138 00000000`035a9e98 00000000`035a8d58 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bce0 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`0358ec18 00000000`0358e978 00000000`0358b2f0 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb
00000000`1d53bd60 000007ff`00d411eb : 000007ff`00e89758 00000000`03573720 00000000`03573480 00000000`0356fdf8 : 0x000007ff`00d411eb

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  0

SYMBOL_NAME:  w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: w3wp

IMAGE_NAME:  w3wp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  49e03238

STACK_COMMAND:  ~16s; .ecxr ; kb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_c00000fd_w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

BUCKET_ID:  X64_APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_STACK_OVERFLOW_w3wp.exe!unknown_error_in_process

WATSON_STAGEONE_URL:  http://watson.microsoft.com/StageOne/w3wp_exe/7_0_6002_18005/49e03238/ntdll_dll/6_0_6002_18541/4ec3e855/c00000fd/000330e5.htm?Retriage=1

Followup: MachineOwner
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use '!sym noisy' to turn on verbose symbol loading messages. That should at least show which symbol(s) are not loading properly.